# how to populate 2 vectors from pairs of numbers separated by commas c++

Tags: c++, vector

The user inputs a list of pairs of numbers separated by commas.
Example... `1, 1 4, 67 90, 87`
OR:

```
30, 50

560, 70

90, 40
```

I have to populate 2 vectors with these numbers. The first of each pair goes into the first vector, and the second number in each pair goes into the second vector.

I know how to read in a vector and how to print one out..

```
vector<int> v;
int i;
while (cin >> i)
{
    v.push_back(i);
}
// print out the vector
for (auto x : v)
{
    cout << x << ", ";
}
```

but I'm not sure how to populate the 2 vectors

Comment: Do the numbers have to be entered with a comma? Such a bugging complication. Why not an empty space?

Comment: yeah they have to have commas

Comment: Handling invalid input might be kind of messy, but maybe: read first value into first vector, read chars until you find the comma, read second value into second vector, and repeat.

Comment: Search the internet for "stackoverflow c++ read file array comma".  There are too many of these questions already.

Comment: I've checked so many of those, they are all just populating 1 array. I need to populate 2 at the same time

Answer (score 0):

How if you do this ?

```
vector<int> v; //vector 1
vector<int> vv; //vector 2
int i;int j;
while (cin >> i)
{
    v.push_back(i);
    cin >> j;
    vv.push_back(j);
}
// print out the first vector
for (auto x : v)
{
    cout << x << ", ";
}

// print out the second vector
for (auto y : vv)
{
    cout << y << " ";
}
```

Comment: might be on the right track but not working. I think i need to account for the commas and spaces in the input as well

Comment: Can you provide the example of input and output format do you need ?

Answer (score 0):

I made what you wanted using the code below. This code assumes that the user inputs are in the form you want (number1,(space) number2) and it stops reading when the word "over" is given. The number1 of every line is stored in the vector named v1 and the number2 of every line is stored in the vector named v2.

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    string inp;
    do
    {
        cin >> inp;
        v.push_back(inp);
    }
    while (inp.compare("over") !=0 );

    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i].compare("over") != 0){
            if (i%2==0){
                v1.push_back( atoi( v[i].c_str() ) );
            } else {
                v2.push_back( atoi( v[i].c_str() ) );
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "v1" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v1[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "v1" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<v2.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v2[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've had to do things like this, I've usually started with a little extraction operator to read and verify (but otherwise ignore) the delimiter:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, char const *delim) {

    while (isspace((unsigned char)*delim))
        ++delim;

    while (isspace((unsigned char)is.peek()))
        is.ignore(1);

    while (*delim == is.peek()) {
        ++delim;
        is.ignore(1);
    }

    if ('\0' != *delim)
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

    return is;
}
```

With this in place, we can do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> u;
std::vector<int> v;

int a, b;
while (is >> a >> "," >> b) {
    u.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
}
```

My immediate inclination, however, would be to consider the relationship between the two values you're reading. If they're closely related, you might be better off creating a structure to hold both, and then create a vector of those structures (with an overload of `operator>>` for that structure type similar to the one shown above).